# How can I remove a new line character in a particular column in a CSV file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a CSV file with 150+ columns, with the new line character as a record separator. The problem lies in one of the columns getting new line characters. For this, I want to remove those.

Input:

```
001|Baker St.
London|3|4|7
002|Penny Lane
Liverpool|88|5|7
```

Output:

```
001|Baker St. London|3|4|7
002|Penny Lane Liverpool|88|5|7
```

Comment: Note that your sample suggests that you want to replace those newlines with a space character as opposed to just delete them.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas AFAIK trying to select the text there is a final whitespace before the newline, so it actually looks just removing the newline.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `sed` to merge the next line into the current one as long as the current line doesn't contain 4 `|` characters:

```
<file sed -e :1 -e 's/|/|/4;t' -e 'N;s/\n/ /;b1'
```

Some `sed` implementations have `-i` or `-i ''` to edit files in-place (`-i.back` to  save the original with a `.back` extension), so with those, you could do:

```
sed -i -e :1 -e 's/|/|/4;t' -e 'N;s/\n/ /;b1' ./*.csv
```

To edit all the non-hidden `csv` files in the current directory.

The same with comments:

```
<file sed '
   :1
     s/|/|/4; # replace the 4th | with itself. Only useful when combined with
              # the next "t" command which branches off if the previous
              # substitution was successful
     t
     # we only reach this point if "t" above did not branch off, that is
     # if the pattern space does not contain 4 "|"s
     N; # append the next line to the pattern space
     s/\n/ /; # replace the newline with a space

   # and then loop again in case the pattern space still does not contain
   # 4 "|"s:
   b1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Relying on 1st field's format (assuming each line should start with a number):

```
awk 'NR == 1{ printf $0; next }
     { printf "%s%s", (/^[0-9]+/? ORS : ""), $0 }
     END{ print "" }' file.csv
```

The output:

```
001|Baker St.London|3|4|7
002|Penny LaneLiverpool|88|5|7
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your command works fine. But using this command we need to write the output to another file, but my case i don't know file name my file is like file_*.csv EG: file_201805072030.csv and i want to do above action in the same file.

Comment: @Vicky, is there only one file in format `file_*.csv`? What should be the name of another file?

Answer (score 2):

Another  GNU `awk` solution relying on 4 times `|` per record:

```
awk -v RS='([^|]+\\|){4}[^|]+\n' '{gsub(/\n/," ",RT); print RT}' file
```

`RS` is set such the that the record contains the 4 separators (even with a newline).

`RT` catches the record set by `RS`. `gsub` removes the newline on the record.

Answer (score 1):

if the first row of your CSV is correct, the following code will work.

```
awk  'NR==1{printf "%s",$0; gsub(/[^|]/,""); nlast=n=length($0); next;} nlast==n{printf "\n";nlast=0} {printf "%s",$0; gsub(/[^|]/,""); nlast+=length($0)} END{print ""}'  file_201805072030.csv > temp.csv && mv -f temp.csv file_201805072030.csv
```

if none of the rows are correct, and if you want to rearrange with 5 columns

```
awk  'NR==1{printf "%s",$0; gsub(/[^|]/,""); nlast=n=4; next;} nlast==n{printf "\n";nlast=0} {printf "%s",$0; gsub(/[^|]/,""); nlast+=length($0)} END{print ""}' file_201805072030.csv > temp.csv && mv -f temp.csv file_201805072030.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Siva, but my input file name is dynamic and i want to do this action on the same file.

Comment: try my edited answer.

Comment: In my case i don't know the file name, my file name will be like file_*.csv, so if i use this comment its not working

Comment: do u want to do it for all CSV files in the directory?

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that any line with only 2 fields should have its trailing newline removed, you can do the following in Perl:

```
$ perl -F"\|" -lane '$#F==1 ? printf : print' file.csv 
001|Baker St.London|3|4|7
002|Penny LaneLiverpool|88|5|7
```

**Important Disclaimer**: as pointed out in the comments by Stéphane Chazelas, this assumes that your input doesn't contain any `%` characters since, if it does, those will be taken as the format specifier for `printf`. This could have unintended consequences ranging from simply printing wrong output to eating *loads* of RAM, if your input has something silly like `%02147483600f%02147483600f%02147483600f%02147483600f`.

#### Explanation

- `-a` : makes `perl` act like `awk`, splitting each input line on the character given by `-F` (so, a `|` here; which needs to be escaped as `\|` since `|` means OR in perl regular expressions) and saving the result as the array `@F`.
- `-l` : this removes trailing newlines from each input line and adds a `'n` t each `print` call.
- `-ne` : read the input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.
- `$#F==1 ? printf : print'` : The `$#F` variable is the number of elements in the array `@F`, so the number of fields. This, therefore, means if the number of fields is 1, then `printf` (which will print the current line without a newline character since the existing one was removed by `-l` and `printf` doesn't add one). If the number of fields is not exactly 1, `print` the line (which, because of the `-l` will add a newline).

The same thing can be expanded to:

```
$ perl -e 'while($line=<STDIN>){
            chomp $line; 
            @fields=split(/\|/,$line); 
            if(scalar(@fields) == 2){
                print "$line";
            } 
            else{
                print "$line\n"
            }
           }' < file.csv 
001|Baker St.London|3|4|7
002|Penny LaneLiverpool|88|5|7
```

---

And an even shorter version suggested by @Sundeep in the comments:

```
perl -F'\|' -ape 'chomp if $#F==1'
```

Comment: you could also use `perl -F'\|' -ape 'chomp if $#F==1'`

Comment: @Sundeep ooh, nice one! I should have thought of that, dammit! Thanks :)

Comment: The first argument of `printf` is the format, it should not be arbitrary data.

Comment: Note  that it wouldn't work if the address was on 3 or more lines

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas no, it assumes the data are as shown by the OP. As for the argument being the format, that's true, of course, but is there anything wrong with doing it this way? Defaulting to `$_` is standard practice in Perl, what corner case are you thinking of where this would be a problem?

Comment: It becomes a problem if the data contains `%` characters for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah! Yes, I see. For instance `echo '%s' | perl -ne 'printf'` prints an empty line.

Comment: Yes, and it can get more severe with things like `echo %02147483600f%02147483600f%02147483600f%02147483600f | perl -ne printf`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh wow. OK, thanks, I added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

With the `sed` tool, you can do like shown:

```
sed  -i  -e '
             /^\(\([^|]*|\)\{2\}\)*[^|]*$/b
             N;s/\n/ /
             s/^/\n/;D
   '     . /*.csv
```

#### Explanation:

1. Branch to end of `sed` code processing for the current pattern space data when an even number of pipes are found.
2. Or, go fetch the next line and append it to the pattern space.
3. Now reapply the `sed` code all over again on the pattern space.

   ```
    perl -i.BAK    -lpe '
        $\ = ( $k += tr/|/|/ ) =~ /[24680]$/ ? "\n" : " ";
     '     . /*.csv
   ```
4. `$k` is a running counter of number if pipes seen at any time.
5. For even we print with a newline, otherwise we join the lines with a space.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/Baker/{printf "%s ",$0; getline; printf "%s\n", $0} \
/Penny/{printf $0; getline; printf "%s\n", $0}' file

001|Baker St. London|3|4|7
002|Penny LaneLiverpool|88|5|7
```

Comment: Why not just say `printf "001|Baker St. London|3|4|7\n002|Penny Lane Liverpool|88|5|7\n"`? The objective is not just to produce the sample output; the objective is to solve the *described* problem, where the given files are just *an **example**.*